# Docker & Hive - Port 50070 ports on Windows permission denied

Tags: docker, hadoop, hive

I want to setup a local hive server and found this repo:

https://github.com/big-data-europe/docker-hive

This is the yaml file I use.

```
version: "3"

services:
  namenode:
    image: bde2020/hadoop-namenode:2.0.0-hadoop2.7.4-java8
    volumes:
      - namenode:/hadoop/dfs/name
    environment:
      - CLUSTER_NAME=test
    env_file:
      - ./hadoop-hive.env
    ports:
      - "50070:50070"
  datanode:
    image: bde2020/hadoop-datanode:2.0.0-hadoop2.7.4-java8
    volumes:
      - datanode:/hadoop/dfs/data
    env_file:
      - ./hadoop-hive.env
    environment:
      SERVICE_PRECONDITION: "namenode:50070"
    ports:
      - "50075:50075"
  hive-server:
    image: bde2020/hive:2.3.2-postgresql-metastore
    env_file:
      - ./hadoop-hive.env
    environment:
      HIVE_CORE_CONF_javax_jdo_option_ConnectionURL: "jdbc:postgresql://hive-metastore/metastore"
      SERVICE_PRECONDITION: "hive-metastore:9083"
    ports:
      - "10000:10000"
  hive-metastore:
    image: bde2020/hive:2.3.2-postgresql-metastore
    env_file:
      - ./hadoop-hive.env
    command: /opt/hive/bin/hive --service metastore
    environment:
      SERVICE_PRECONDITION: "namenode:50070 datanode:50075 hive-metastore-postgresql:5432"
    ports:
      - "9083:9083"
  hive-metastore-postgresql:
    image: bde2020/hive-metastore-postgresql:2.3.0
  presto-coordinator:
    image: shawnzhu/prestodb:0.181
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"

volumes:
  namenode:
  datanode:
```

Error:

```
Error starting userland proxy: Bind for 0.0.0.0:50075: unexpected error Permission denied
```

The ports >50000 are blocked on windows, I don´t have admin rights on my company pc, so I tried to map the ports like this:

```
ports:
  - "40070:50070"

environment:
  SERVICE_PRECONDITION: "namenode:40070 datanode:40075 hive-metastore-postgresql:5432"
```

This will let me get the Container started, but the container seem not to be able to communicate.

```
hive-metastore_1             | [1/100] check for namenode:40070...
hive-metastore_1             | [1/100] namenode:40070 is not available yet
hive-metastore_1             | [1/100] try in 5s once again ...
956a5237dbe2_docker-hive_datanode_1 | [4/100] check for namenode:40070...
956a5237dbe2_docker-hive_datanode_1 | [4/100] namenode:40070 is not available yet
```

I tried to change both ports:

```
ports:
  - "40070:40070"
```

This will not work, because some IPs seem to be hardcoded:

```
ded7410db1b9_docker-hive_namenode_1 | 21/10/08 12:39:05 INFO hdfs.DFSUtil: Starting Web-server for hdfs at: http://0.0.0.0:50070
ded7410db1b9_docker-hive_namenode_1 | 21/10/08 12:39:05 INFO http.HttpServer2: Jetty bound to port 50070
```

Does anyone know how to get this running?

Answer (score 1):

With the following:

```yaml
    ports:
      - "40070:50070"
```

all you are doing is directing traffic from host port 40070 to container port 50070.

So to access "namenode" from the host machine for example:

`localhost:40070`

And to access "namenode" inside the compose network:

`namenode:50070`

Service precondition with BDE checks the container and the port repeatedly to see if the service is running before setting up its own services to ensure things are ready first. You have not changed the port running on the container, so your containers should still communicate via port `50070`.

You have incorrectly changed the precondition to scan instead for your host port `40070`, whereas it should look for the internal network container port `50070` regardless of host port.

Change it to the following:

```yaml
    ports:
      - "40070:50070"
    
    environment:
      SERVICE_PRECONDITION: "namenode:50070 datanode:50075 hive-metastore-postgresql:5432"
```

You can change the operating ports on Hive etc. with the environmental variable file provided, but you shouldn't need to. Exposing host port 40070 to container port 50070 has no impact on the operation of the docker services.